# JavaScript function passing value not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction(demox)">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="demox"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(cat) {
var dog = document.getElementById( cat);
dog.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to pass an id value of "demox" to a js function to display some text with an onclick event, but it doesn't seem to work. what is the problem here?

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction('demox')">Click me</button> Check this

Comment: `demox` is a string (within another string) so you have to wrap it with quotes. Wrap demox with either single quotes (`'`), since you've already used doubles for the enclosing string, or use (`\"`) to put double quotes _inside_ a string wrapped with double-quotes. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find script modified which solve your issue here.

https://jsbin.com/yitovikete/edit?html,output

Generally, I would suggest you to add `<script>` tag within the header of your HTML page like this:

https://jsbin.com/yitovikete/1/edit?html,output

This is good when you need to do something while the body is loading, or want to maybe make some ajax requests.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction('demox')">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="demox"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(cat) {
var dog = document.getElementById( cat);
dog.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```